# Facebook setting get wrong request uri

Tags: php, symfony, docker, facebook-login, ngrok

I have installed docker on my machine + symfony 4. I try to implement facebook login and for that I installed ngrok because I have some problems with https, so ngrok generated this link : https://f7f8d7d3.ngrok.io. I put in facebook developper app this url

When I push on button Login with facebook I get the error : 
Insecure Login Blocked: You can’t get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

But I saw in url that the request_uri is the old host : 
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=634818730276116&state=73109d9bebdfd1670ccfff86702e001c&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%project.loc%2Fsecured%2Flogin_facebook&display=popup&auth_type=rerequest

redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%project.loc

I don't understand why.

My implimentation

Connect with Facebook

Connect with Google

```
</form>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId      : '634818730276116',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
            channelUrl : '//mysite.com/channel.html',      // Channel file for x-domain comms
            status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
            xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function fb_login() {
        console.log("Facebook Login");
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // connected
                document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}";
            } else {
                // not_authorized
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "facebook"}) }}";
                    }
                }, {scope: 'email'});
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

So the idea is how to change this request_uri, and why is the old one ? I will appreciate your help. Thx in advance and sorry for my english. No one idea how to solve that ? :(

Comment: The duplicate answer explains why, and offers a Laravel (Symfony-based) solution. The Symfony docs also discuss this at https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you very much for answer, so the idea will be to get the ip of my ngrok that running and put in this array : 'Request::setTrustedProxies([{ip_of_ngrok}] ?'

Comment: I'd personally just trust `*` on local development. You wouldn't want that in production, though.

Comment: I tried like this : Request::setTrustedProxies(
    ['*'],
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL
);
But still I have the problem

Comment: @ceejayoz any other ideas if you are please

Comment: @ceejayoz so that is not a duplicate question yes ?